# Is it possible to scan an image from the command line?

Tags: scanning

Is there a tool that scans images from the command line? I am looking like scanimage on linux that works like this:

```
scanimage > image.pnm
```

I've tried googling and checked if ImageCapture is scriptable via applescript but no results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do it with built in tools, but there is an OS X version of [SANE](http://www.sane-project.org/) that should be able to do exactly what you request (`scanimage` > image.pnm).

## SANE

> This is a TWAIN datasource for MacOS X that aquires images using the SANE backend libraries. The SANE backend libraries provide access to a large range of scanners connected through SCSI or USB. For a complete list see the documentation on the [SANE project homepage](http://www.sane-project.org).

It's available at http://www.ellert.se/twain-sane/

Answer (score 7):

You might also be interested in scanline, which does what you're requesting:

http://blog.scottkleper.com/scanline-command-line-scanner-for-mac/

(Disclaimer: I wrote scanline. It's free and open source)

Comment: Up vote for you and kudos for mentioning your association.